# Japanese keyboard layout in Windows 7 doesn't correspond to what's written on the physical keyboard

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout

I have an English version of Windows 7, but my keyboard is Japanese.

However, even though I choose a Japanese keyboard (Microsoft IME) under Keyboard and Languages, the layout isn't right. I think it's English layout, but I can't be sure.

Anyway, I want the layout and usage to be exactly like it is on a Japanese Windows 7, as there are some nice (mouse free) shortcuts to change between input modes. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can edit the registry to change from a 101 key keyboard to a 106 key keyboard. Go to:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\i8042prt\Parameters`

Change the value of `LayerDriver JPN` from "kbd101.dll" to "kdb106.dll", and three other settings.

Comment: I also had to change the KeyboardSubType to 2. I followed the official Microsoft directions found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927824

Comment: OverrideKeyboardIdentifier also needs change from 101 to 106.

Answer (score 2):

Find the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\i8042prt\Parameters
```

change these entries:

```
LayerDriver JPN REG_SZ kbd106.dll
OverrideKeyboardIdentifier REG_SZ PCAT_106KEY
OverrideKeyboardSubtype DWORD 2
OverrideKeyboardType DWORD 7
```