# Japanese Keyboard/US Keyboard, plugged in at same time

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, japanese

Using [Japanese keyboard layout in Windows 7 doesn't correspond to what's written on the physical keyboard](https://superuser.com/questions/414969/japanese-keyboard-layout-in-windows-7-doesnt-correspond-to-whats-written-on-th) as a jumping off point, I managed to get my **real** Japanese/106 keyboard working side by side with my US/101 keyboard, both are USB.

Immediately I am running into issues though... It appears that the 101 vs 106 key option is set globally, not on a keyboard by keyboard basis. Windows now thinks that my US keyboard is a 106 Japanese keyboard... my English keyboard now has the layout of my Japanese keyboard, which is very troubling.

Can I run both keyboards side by side on the same box with different layouts? I wouldn`t think I`d need IME for this, but not sure how else to approach it.

This appears to be how to do what I am trying to do if you have a PS/2 keyboard (maybe, and win2k)  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/280725

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, that's neat.  Turns out that Windows respects your current IME mode and switches your keyboard layout depending on the mode.

If you have ENG IME running then it will use the 101 keyboard layout.
If you have JP IME running then it will use the 106 keyboard layout.